# How to avoid IP & MAC spoofing and block desired ports for Qemu/KVM virtual machines via nft or nftables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, kvm-virtualization, nftables

I have a Debian 11 server that is running several Qemu/KVM virtual machines ( not using `libvirtd` created purely with Qemu commands ), I've created a network bridge and each VM has its own TAP device connected to the bridge. Please consider that I know avoiding MAC spoofing is easily done in `libvirtd` via its network filters but I aim to configure it myself for my Qemu-created VMs. My real interface is called `eth0`, my bridge is called `br0`, and one of my VMs TAP devices connected to this bridge is called `vm0`.

What I want to do is that use nftables to drop all `OUTPUT` packets except for `eth0` and `br0` in the first place, and then allow `OUTPUT` packets of my TAP devices only if the source MAC address is the same as the actual MAC address I see in my `ip -c a` output that I've assigned myself while creating the VM, in other words, I want to avoid MAC spoofing on the VMs via `nftables`. In addition, I want to block SMTP ports.

I have already created some `iptables` and `ebtables` rules to achieve my desired outcome however after learning that `nftables` is a framework to replace both of them and that achieving such results is more efficient with it, I want to migrate these rules to `nftables`, however, I can't wrap my head around how to write these rules.

My rules are as follows:

#### iptables rules, originally learned from [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/270383/linux-kvm-iptables-prevent-guest-spoofing-by-matching-ipmac-address-on-bridg):

```bash
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m physdev --physdev-in vm1 --physdev-is-bridged -j 0-out
iptables -t filter -A 0-out -m mac ! --mac-source <SOME_MAC_ADDRESS> -j DROP
iptables -t filter -A 0-out -s 0.0.0.0/32 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 68 --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter -A 0-out ! -s <SOME_IP_ADDRESS> -j DROP
iptables -t filter -A 0-out -j RETURN
```

#### ebtables rules:

```bash
# OUTPUT rules

ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-sport 25 -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-sport 587 -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-sport 465 -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-sport 25 -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-sport 587 -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -p IPv4 -o vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-sport 465 -j DROP

# INPUT rules

ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-dport 25 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-dport 587 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol tcp --ip-dport 465 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-dport 25 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-dport 587 -j DROP
ebtables -A INPUT -p IPv4 -i vm0 --ip-protocol udp --ip-dport 465 -j DROP
```

I know the combination of using both `ebtables` and `iptables` for the basically same reason is a bit unorthodox, this is because I am new to the whole thing and I wrote these rules learning from several sources, however, this is another reason to use `nftables` to unify them.

Any help is appreciated, either the ruleset syntax itself or hints and guides.

Many thanks in advance.