# nft bridge family ruleset not working

Tags: linux, networking, debian, linux-networking, nftables

I have a Debian 11 server and I am running a Qemu/KVM virtual machine on it created via Qemu commands, there is a bridge device on the server named `br0` and the VM has a TAP device named `vm0`.

I want to avoid MAC/IP spoofing by creating an `nft` ruleset.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work meaning when I change the MAC address via the `macchanger` tool the packets don't drop:

```bash
nft add table bridge filter
nft add chain bridge filter forward \{ type filter hook forward priority filter \; policy accept \;}
nft add rule bridge filter forward iifname vm0 ether type ip ether saddr != <MAC_ADDR_ALLOWED> ether type ip ip saddr != <IP_ADDR_ALLOWED> drop
```

The output of the `nft list ruleset` looks like below:

```bash
table bridge filter {
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "vm0" ether type ip ether saddr != <MAC_ADDR_ALLOWED> ip <IP_ADDR_ALLOWED> drop
        }
}
```

I reckon I'm doing something wrong, any help is appreciated,

**Question:** How to create a valid rule?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to achieve this is as follows:

```bash
nft add table bridge filter
nft add chain bridge filter forward '{ type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept }'
nft add chain bridge filter allowed-mac
nft add rule bridge filter forward iifname "vm0" ether type ip jump allowed-mac
nft add rule bridge filter allowed-mac ether type ip ether saddr <MAC_ADDR_ALLOWED> ip saddr <IP_ADDR_ALLOWED> accept
nft add rule bridge filter allowed-mac drop
```

Which gives the following output:

```bash
nft list ruleset                           
table bridge filter {
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "vm0" ether type ip jump allowed-mac
        }

        chain allowed-mac {
                ether saddr <MAC_ADDR_ALLOWED> ip saddr <IP_ADDR_ALLOWED> accept
                drop
        }
}
```

### There is a fully explained post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108207/how-to-avoid-ip-mac-spoofing-and-block-desired-ports-for-qemu-kvm-virtual-mach)